# Why in this loop messages that are in if statement are caller only after loop ends?

Tags: java

Please explain why in this function `System.out.println(msg + ": " + count++);` will be called after **while** end.

Example: `printWithDelay(2, "Hello");`
Result: Only after count reach 9 (~20 sec), all stack of `System.out.println()` will be displayed.

```
static void printWithDelay(int sec, String msg){
    int count = 0;
    long eventTime = System.nanoTime() + ((long)Math.pow(10, 10)*sec);
    while(count < 10){
        if(System.nanoTime() > eventTime){
            System.out.println(msg + ": " + count++);
        }
    }
}
```

Wanted result: the message displays after exactly when `if` statement is true.

Comment: count++
it is increasing

Comment: When `System.nanoTime() > eventTime` is true, the print statement will run 10 times in a few seconds. It's actually in the while loop but it's too quick

Comment: .... what ? i find it hard to understand what you want tbh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not be called after the end of the loop, but right away as you
seem to want. Are you expecting the output to come out incrementally
and evenly spaced over the timeframe? If so something similar to this
might work:

```java
static void printWithDelay(int sec, String msg){
    int count = 0;
    long eventTime = System.nanoTime() + ((long)Math.pow(10, 9)*sec);
    while(count < 10){
        if(System.nanoTime() > eventTime){
            eventTime = System.nanoTime() + ((long)Math.pow(10, 9)*sec);
            System.out.println(msg + ": " + count++);
        }
    }
}
```

However busy waiting, which is what you are doing is not very nice and you should
probably use `sleep` instead.

If this isn't your concern you need to tell us a little bit more about what you
are expecting the code to do.

Answer (score 1):

it's either because it's too fast or there is a problem with your if !
i suppose it's just because it's too fast ! To make sure of that, add a Thread.sleep(1000); and see now the result ... 
change the 1000 by any value in ms that you wish, but I suggest that you try to make it sleep 1 second for the moment just to make sure if the problem is related to speed before making other suggestions.

```
static void printWithDelay(int sec, String msg){
    int count = 0;
    long eventTime = System.nanoTime() + ((long)Math.pow(10, 10)*sec);
    while(count < 10){
        if(System.nanoTime() > eventTime){
            System.out.println(msg + ": " + count++);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Math.pow(10,9) instead.  And reset your timer inside the if block...

```
static void printWithDelay(int sec, String msg){
    int count = 0;
    long eventTime = System.nanoTime() + ((long)Math.pow(10, 9)*sec);
    while(count < 10){
        if(System.nanoTime() > eventTime){
            System.out.println(msg + ": " + count++);
            eventTime = System.nanoTime() + ((long)Math.pow(10, 9)*sec);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer to why your version doesn't work, but a simple version of what it *looks* like you're trying to do is...

```
static void printWithDelay(int sec, String msg){
    for(int count=0; count < 10; count++) {
        Thread.sleep(sec*1000);
        System.out.println(msg + ": " + count++);
    }
}
```